# Overloading operator[] for a template Polynom class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, square-bracket

I am writing a template `Polynom<T>` class where `T` is the numeric type of its coefficients.

The coefficients of the polynom are stored in an `std::vector<T> coefficients`, where `coefficients[i]` corresponds to `x^i` in a real polynom. (so the powers of x are in increasing order).

It is guaranteed that `coefficients` vector always contains at least one element. - for a zero polynom it is `T()`.

I want to overload the `operator[]` to do the following:

1. The index passed to the operator[] corresponds to the power of X whose coefficient we want to modify / read.
2. If the user wants to just **read** the coefficient, it should throw for negative indices, return `coefficients.at(i)` for indices within the stored range - and **reasonably** return 0 for all other indices, not throw.
3. If the user wants to **modify** the coefficient, it should throw for negative indices, but let user modify all other indices freely, even if the index specified is bigger than or equal to `coefficients.size()`. So we want to somehow resize the vector.

The main problem I have collided with is as follows:

1.

How do I distinguish between the read case and the write case? One person left me without an explanation but said that writing two versions:

```
const T& operator[] (int index) const;
T& operator[] (int index);
```

was insufficient. However, I thought that the compiler would prefer the const version in the read case, won't it?

2.

I want to make sure that no trailing zeros are ever stored in the `coefficients` vector. So I somehow have to know in advance, "before" I return a mutable `T&` of my coefficient, what value user wants to assign. And I know that `operator[]` doesn't receive a second argument.

Obviously, if this value is not zero (not T()), then I have to resize my vector and set the appropriate coefficient to the value passed.

But I cannot do it in advance (before returning a `T&` from `operator[]`), because if the value to be assigned is T(), then, provided I resize my coefficients vector in advance, it will eventually have lots of trailing "zeroes".

*Of course I can check for trailing zeroes in every other function of the class and remove them in that case. Seems a very weird decision to me, and I want every function to start working in assumption that there are no zeroes at the end of the vector if its size > 1.*

Could you please advise me as concrete solution as possible to this problem?
I heard something about writing an inner class implicitly convertible to `T&` with overloaded `operator=`, but I lack the details.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option you could try (I haven't tested this):

```
template<typename T>
class MyRef{
private:
   int index;
   Polynom<T>*p;
public:
    MyRef(int index, Polynom<T>*p) : index(index), p(p) { }

    MyRef<T>& operator=(T const&t); //and define these appropriately
    T operator T() const;         
};
```

and define:

```
    MyRef<T> operator[](int index){
        return MyRef<T>(index, this);
    }
```

This way when you assign a value to the "reference" it should have access to all the needed data in the polynomial, and take the appropriate actions.

I am not familiar enough with your implementation, so I'll instead give an example of a very simple dynamic array that works as follows:

- you can read from any `int index` without concern; elements not previously written to should read off as `0`;
- when you write to an element past the end of the currently allocated array, it is reallocated, and the newly allocated elements are initialized to `0`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class my_array{
private:
    T* _data;
    int _size;

    class my_ref{

        private:
            int index;
            T*& obj;
            int&size;
        public:
            my_ref(T*& obj, int&size, int index)
                : index(index), obj(obj), size(size){}

            my_ref& operator=(T const& t){

                if (index>=size){    
                    obj = (T*)realloc(obj, sizeof(T)*(index+1) );
                    while (size<=index)
                        obj[size++]=0;
                }
                obj[index] = t;

                return *this;
            }

            //edit:this one should allow writing, say, v[1]=v[2]=v[3]=4;
            my_ref& operator=(const my_ref&r){              
                operator=( (T) r);
                return *this;
            }

            operator T() const{
                return (index>=size)?0:obj[index];
            }

    };

public:
    my_array() : _data(NULL), _size(0) {}

    my_ref operator[](int index){
        return my_ref(_data,_size,index);
    }

    int size() const{ return _size; }

};

int main(){

    my_array<int> v;

    v[0] = 42;
    v[1] = 51;
    v[5] = 5; v[5]=6;
    v[30] = 18;

    v[2] = v[1]+v[5];
    v[4] = v[8]+v[1048576]+v[5]+1000;

    cout << "allocated elements: " <<  v.size() << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<31;i++)
        cout << v[i] << " " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's a very simple example and not very efficient in its current form but it should prove the point.

Eventually you might want to overload `operator&` to allow things like `*(&v[0] + 5) = 42;` to work properly. For this example, you could have that `operator&` gives a `my_pointer` which defines `operator+` to do arithmetic on its `index`  field and return a new `my_pointer`. Finally, you can overload `operator*()` to go back to a `my_ref`.

Comment: Thank you!
Could you please also clarify the following:

1. Should I make this class inner & private?
2. Can I return a reference to an instance of a private class?

Comment: I've updated my example to use a private nested class. It still works (see: http://ideone.com/dRr4D) but I haven't used nested classes too much in the past so I don't know what the best practices are.

Comment: This won't cover use cases such as `int &r = v[1]; r = 3;`.

Comment: True, there are limitations. But you can always (assuming `my_ref` were public) use `my_array<int>::my_ref r = v[1]; r= 3;` if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is a proxy class (untested code follows):

```
template<typename T> class Polynom
{
public:
   class IndexProxy;
   friend class IndexProxy;
   IndexProxy operator[](int);
   T operator[](int) const;
   // ...
private:
   std::vector<T> coefficients;
};

template<typename T> class Polynom<T>::IndexProxy
{
public:
  friend class Polynom<T>;
  // contrary to convention this assignment does not return an lvalue,
  // in order to be able to avoid extending the vector on assignment of 0.0
  T operator=(T const& t)
  {
    if (theIndex >= thePolynom.coefficients.size())
      thePolynom.coefficients.resize(theIndex+1);
    thePolynom.coefficients[theIndex] = t;
    // the assignment might have made the polynom shorter
    // by assigning 0 to the top-most coefficient
    while (thePolynom.coefficients.back() == T())
      thePolynom.coefficients.pop_back();
    return t;
  }
  operator T() const
  {
    if (theIndex >= thePolynom.coefficients.size())
      return 0;
    return thePolynom.coefficients[theIndex];
  }
private:
  IndexProxy(Polynom<T>& p, int i): thePolynom(p), theIndex(i) {}
  Polynom<T>& thePolynom;
  int theIndex;
}

template<typename T>
  Polynom<T>::IndexProxy operator[](int i)
  {
    if (i < 0) throw whatever;
    return IndexProxy(*this, i);
  }

template<typename T>
  T operator[](int i)
{
  if (i<0) throw whatever;
  if (i >= coefficients.size()) return T();
  return coefficients[i];
}
```

Obviously the code above is not optimized (especially the assignment operator has clearly room for optimization).

Comment: +1. May I ask you to clarify why you chose to not make `operator=` return an lvalue? I'm trying to think of possible problems when it does return a `&` but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: Returning T& would have implied to have an object to bind it to, which might not exist in the case of assigning 0. As I only now notice, I could also have returned a reference to IndexProxy itself. But the only extra code that enables would be of the form you wouldn't want to write anyway; the code which you might want to write (binding the result of the assignment expression to a reference to T) would still not work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. As for the last part, you're right, it didn't work, I added another overload for the `operator=` to make that case work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot distinguish between read and write with operator overloads.  The best you can do is distinguish between usage in a `const` setting and a non-`const` setting, which is what your code snippet does.  So:

```
Polynomial &poly = ...;

poly[i] = 10;  // Calls non-const version
int x = poly[i];  // Calls non-const version

const Polynomial &poly = ...;

poly[i] = 10;   // Compiler error!
int x = poly[i]  // Calls const version
```

It sounds like the answer to both your questions, therefore, is to have separate `set` and `get` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions to your problem:

1. Instead of storing the coefficients in a `std::vector<T>` store them in a `std::map<unsigned int, T>`. This way you will ever only store non-zero coefficients. You could create your own `std::map`-based container that would consume zeros stored into it. This way you also save some storage for polynomials of the form x^n with large n.
2. Add an inner class that will store an index (power) and coefficient value. You would return a reference to an instance of this inner class from `operator[]`. The inner class would overwrite `operator=`. In the overridden `operator=` you would take the index (power) and coefficient stored in inner class instance and flush them to the `std::vector` where you store your coefficients.

Comment: `std::map` also stores zero elements. Moreover, if you ask it for an element it does not yet contain, it *creates* is with the value zero. For example: `std::map<int,int> m; int k=m[1]; k=m[3]; std::cout << m.size();` prints 2, because now there are two key-value pairs in the map: (1,0) and (3,0).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The only way I can think of is to provide a special member-function for adding new coefficients.

The compiler decides between the `const` and non-`const` version by looking at the type of `Polynom`, and not by checking what kind of operation is performed on the return-value.